# Polymer 1.0 deep path array binding

Tags: polymer

I am trying to get the following to work. It initially of course renders the content of parentItems, but when changing it, the template looping over the parentItems is not invoked. I have looked at the notifyPath, but am not sure if this is the right direction

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js'></script>
        <link rel='import' href='bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <dom-module id='my-element'>
            <template>
                <template is='dom-repeat' items='{{parentValues}}'>
                    <template is='dom-repeat' items='{{item.childValues}}'>
                        <div>{{item.value}}</div>
                    </template>
                </template>
                <paper-button on-tap='click'>click me</paper-button>
            </template>
        </dom-module>
        <script>
            Polymer({
                is: 'my-element',
                properties: {
                    parentValues: {
                        type: Array,
                        value: function() { return [ { childValues: [ { value: 'original value' } ] } ]}
                    }
                },

                click: function() {
                    this.parentValues[0].childValues[0].value = 'new value';
                }
            });
        </script>
        <my-element></my-element>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I get it to work?

Thanks a million :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `dom-repeat` with `as` scope in your binding, and notifyPath to bubble up change to your array when changed

```js
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js'></script>
        <link rel='import' href='bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <dom-module id='my-element'>
            <template is='dom-repeat' items='{{parentValues}}' as ="parent">
                    <template is='dom-repeat' items='{{parent.childValues}}' as="child">
                        <div>{{child.value}}</div>
                    </template>
                </template>
                <paper-button on-tap='click'>click me</paper-button>
            </template>
        </dom-module>
        <script>
            Polymer({
                is: 'my-element',
                properties: {
                    parentValues: {
                        type: Array,
                        value: function() { return [ { childValues: [ { value: 'original value' } ] } ]}
                    }
                },

                click: function() {
                // notify path to the properties using the polymer syntax
                    this.set('parentValues.0.childValues.0.value','changed value');
                }
            });
        </script>
        <my-element></my-element>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah, got it ... thanks a lot ... and sorry for the delay in my answer

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue, which @jeanPokou solved was that you need to use the 'this.set(Object, New Value)' to set the value on the nested object.

You can check this video from the 'Ask Polymer' series to learn more about why it doesn't update nested values: https://youtu.be/0GxteaIaj2Q

Comment: Yes, got it ... now I did mistake of simplifying my example so much that the problem vanished :-). The parentValues array of arrays does not just have one value in it, it has lots. So therefore @jeanPokou, using this.set becomes a rather big exercise. The question is what is the minimum that I can "set" to get it to trigger the "property effect"